# Pen Drive Control

Tags: linux, embedded, usb-drive

I want to control television through pen drive. What should I do with pen drive means at hardware and software level?
What type of kernel should I load and how I load the kernel and bootloader in pen driver?

Answer (score 3):

A pen drive has no CPU so it's not clear how this could ever work. A pen drive is just some memory and a USB interface. To control a TV you need some kind of processor and a suitable interface (e.g. infra red).

Comment: but pen drive also has the controller..so i was thinking to load the kernel in its controller.

Comment: The controller is just a dedicated USB micro-controller - even if you could load new firmware into it (which you probably can't), what could you do then ? You have no interface other than as a USB slave.

Comment: so i need a pen drive and processor to control it right....because i m making a final project in which i want to design set top box which has storage and can be control by my server....i was thinking about the pen drive....can you help what should i do....where do i get the proper information about these things?

Comment: I think the pen drive is probably irrelevant - it sounds like all you need to do is build what is commonly known as a `media center` - this is essentially just a PC with video output suitable for a TV. Try Googling for "media center".

Comment: yeah...but i want server is on onw side and client is television...i have to first load data on client side then show it on tv...can media center do it?

Comment: Your requirements are just too vague at the moment - this makes it hard to give any specific advice - read up on media centers and see if that helps you to get a more specific idea of your actual requirements.